# How to access header of mail in Outlook 2019 using VSTO?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

In order to read the header a mail item in Outlook, I found the following solution for Outlook 2010 but it does not work with Outlook 2019 (and probably also not with Outlook 365).

```
var mailItem = item as MailItem;
if (mailItem != null)
{
    var header = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E/");
...
```

Unfortunately I receive this error message:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E/" cannot be parsed or has an invalid format.'

So, how to read the header of an e-mail using C# and VSTO? What is considered to be best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DASL name is invalid - you have an extra trailing `"/"`. Use `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"`.

Be prepared to handle "not found" errors - no MAPI property is guaranteed to be present.

If you want to see DASL property names for existing properties, take a look at a message with that property set with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, select the property, copy the value of the DASL edit box.

Comment: It really made the trick! Thanks a lot - also for providing OutlookSpy :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that such property exists on the item. Composed items and in-house Exchange items may not have this property set up. Use the `MFCMAPI` or `OutlookSpy` for exploring internals.

Typically you need to use the following code:

```
Outlook.PropertyAccessor oPA = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
string headers= (string)oPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS);
```

where the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` constant stands for the string `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E` .

Handling the exception is the only way to check whether such property exists on the item - older versions of Outlook used to return null, but the latest versions always throw the exception.

Comment: If you put the two lines of your code together then you obtain exactly what I posted, namely mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E/"). Even if I checked whether such a property exists, I wouldn't win much: I still would not know where to take the header from in this case.

Comment: Yes, the code is the same except the cast to a string. There is no other way to retrieve a header info. Does the property exist on the item?